# Why can't Dart calculate simple double value?

Tags: dart

I found this very simple calculation results incorrect: 0.19999999999999998.
(This is happened on Dartpad too)

```
void main() {
    print(-0.1 + 0.3);
}
```

Why this is happened, and how to avoid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are loosing precision when using the type double.

To avoid that you have a few alternatives:

1. Use some decimal library like https://pub.dev/packages/decimal
2. Multiply by the number of significant digits and do the math using integers, some more information on a related SO question [Dart double division precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654642/dart-double-division-precision)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the internal representation of floating point numbers that crops up in almost all programming languages; c.f. this [tutorial on floating point representation](https://floating-point-gui.de/).

What's going on under the hood is that the string "-0.1" is converted into a string of bits that correspond to a particular number that is approximately equal to the value $-0.1$; same for $0.3$.  When you subtract them, these approximation errors line up in such a way as to produce a result that you get by doing the math symbolically.

If you really need "exact" math on numbers like this, you can look into packages that provide either a [Decimal](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal) or a [Rational](https://pub.dev/packages/rational) type.