# In Dart language multiplying or dividing one number by another returns the wrong result. How do I avoid the error without rounding

Tags: dart, decimal, division

I multiply the number `762` by the number `0.11`
But the result is `83.82000000000001` (not correct)

How to avoid this number `83.82000000000001`.

I want to get the correct number `83.82`.

I don't want to specify decimals because other math operation may return number with different decimals.

```dart
void main(){
  int  number = 762;
  print('number= $number');
  double d =  0.11 * number;
  print('number * 0.11 = $d');
  print('number * 0.11 = ${d.toString()}');
  
  // I don't want to specify the decimals
  print('this is the correct result= ${d.toStringAsFixed(2)}'); 
}
```

Result:

```
number= 762
number * 0.11 = 83.82000000000001
number * 0.11 = 83.82000000000001
this is the correct result= 83.82
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3001761

Comment: Welcome to floating point!  Some numbers are exact, others not so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is correct based on the limitations of the `double` type, which you can read more about here:
[Dart double division precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654642/dart-double-division-precision)

But if you want to do the calculation with infinite precision, you can use the [`decimal`](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal) package to do e.g. the following:

```dart
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

void main() {
  Decimal number = Decimal.fromInt(762);
  print('number= $number');
  Decimal d = Decimal.parse('0.11') * number;
  print('number * 0.11 = $d');
}
```

Which will output:

```
number= 762
number * 0.11 = 83.82
number * 0.11 = 83.82
```